# Installing python vtk module on Windows 11 using pip: "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, python-3.7, vtk

I have installed the vtk module in an embedded python3.7.9 folder using the command

```
python.exe -m pip install vtk
```

But when I try "import vtk" I get the following error:

```
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

I went into Lib\site-packages\vtkmodules and I found "vtkCommonCore-9.2.dll". In fact, all .dll files have the -9.2 qualifier in the name.

When I went into an older install where vtk can be successfully imported, I found "vtkCommonCore.dll" and others without a version qualifier.

I assume it's this "-9.2" "qualifier that's causing problems. But I don't understand why they are not there in the older install.

P.S. I just checked the vtk version of the working install and it's "9.0.1". Maybe vtk 9.2 broke the module for older versions of python?