# Cannot import vtk module on Window's machine

Tags: python, importerror, vtk, dllimport

For reproducibility, I'm using python 3.10.9, running Windows 10 Pro, version 22H2, build 19045.2965. And I'm trying to install vtk 9.2.6.

I create a virtual env with `python -m venv env`, activate the env, and install vtk with `pip install vtk`.

When I try to import vtk after installing it, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\Bryce\Documents\DebuggingVTK\env\lib\site-packages\vtk.py", line 4, in <mod
ule>
    from vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing vtkCommonCore: The specified module could not be found.
```

I see it's similar to this issue: [Installing python vtk module on Windows 11 using pip: "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427457/installing-python-vtk-module-on-windows-11-using-pip-dll-load-failed-the-spec/76908918#76908918)

But they are running python 3.7 and Windows 11 (plus there is no solution posted...). From what I read something with dll linking changed in Python 3.8, so I figure my problem might have a different solution.

I've tried running `os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Users\Bryce\Documents\DebuggingVTK\env\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules')` as I saw suggested in numerous places. This folder is where I see all the module's dll files, such as vtkCommonCore-9.2.6.dll. This had no effect.

I also tried adding this folder to PATH and PYTHONPATH, to no effect. The vexing thing is my coworkers have done the exact same setup, but with a slightly older version of Windows 10, and have had no issues, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it. And I'm completely new to Windows so I'm not familiar with the landscape.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by upgrading VTK to 9.3.0rc1